# Has anyone achieved to use ODBC connection from Excel file into Powerpivot?

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I have installed Powerpivot for Excel 2010. I don't have Access 2010 so I thought could I arrange the data in the similar manner as I would for a database.

I'm wanting to query an excel file that has rows of self-generated data into Powerpivot in order to perform simple pivot table. In a sense attempt to get an overview of information about a data set.

At the moment, I'm unable to get set up correctly the ODBC I'm hoping I need to accept an Excel file and to get PowerPivot to accept a database from an Excel file.

Edit: I come to understand that I need to set up a table correctly in Excel so that the ODBC works correctly. Does the picture I provided be right manner to set up a table or any other manner?

[image]

Has anyone attempted to do this and if so what would the steps be?

Thanks,
Peter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter, I am working on the basis that your data is in a recognizable table on a worksheet (and that you are not interested in using the standard Excel import method through 'From Other Sources')

If you create the connection to the Excel file in a very particular way it is possible to then query it as if it were a database.

- Create a Connection to the spreadsheet in question in Excel through Data>Connections>Add.
- In the PowerPivot window on the Design tab click on existing connections and find the connection you just created. Select the connection and Open.
- You need to name the connection and then you will be offered the normal import options. Select the sheet you want to get the table from (its actually not important which one you choose at this point).
- Once the table has been imported you can re-enter the setup through the 'table properties' on the design tab and you will now be able to 'Switch to' the query editor at which point you can not only write SQL to query your DB but reference any other .xlsx you like.

Jacob

Comment: Excel doesn't recognize any tables I have in my sheet. I thought by selecting data and formatting as a table be all I require. Then I save the sheet and select the ODBC to it. Trouble is, Jacob it cannot find any tables???

Comment: Peter, apologies for my ambiguous use of the term 'table'. Excel has a table functionality that can be applied to your data using CTRL+T. Your data does not have to be in a 'table' to be imported to Excel using the methods I explained above, but obviously the import will not be useful if it isnt in a table layout with rows and columns etc.

Comment: Have a look at this video - the excel import happens after 17 minutes and 8 seconds http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URy_uQYS49s

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use a linked table from the excel sheet which has the data - is there any reason why you have not considered this as an option?

Comment: when you mentioned linked table would I be right in saying that you mean data that has been formatted as a table so Excel puts extra meta-data about the table?